# How to force update given branch of remotes and heads metadata using JGIT?

Tags: git, jgit

I have an application that does not fully support git. The requirement is that remote repository is always the single source of truth so

1. Commits are always pushed right away
2. Fetch is done before any interaction to update local repository state

This is how I am fetching given branch on request

```java
private void fetchBranch(String branch) throws GitAPIException {
        RefSpec ref = new RefSpec().setSourceDestination(Constants.R_HEADS + branch, Constants.R_REMOTES + Constants.DEFAULT_REMOTE_NAME + "/" + branch)
                .setForceUpdate(true);
        RefSpec ref2 = new RefSpec().setSourceDestination(Constants.R_HEADS + branch, Constants.R_HEADS + branch)
                .setForceUpdate(true);
        git.fetch()
                .setRemote(Constants.DEFAULT_REMOTE_NAME)
                .setRefSpecs(ref2,ref)
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentials.orElse(null))
                .setProgressMonitor(new FetchProgressMonitor(log, configuration))
                .setForceUpdate(true)
                .call();

//        git.branchCreate()
//                .setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.SET_UPSTREAM)
//                .setName(branch)
//                .setStartPoint(Constants.DEFAULT_REMOTE_NAME + "/" + branch)
//                .setForce(true)
//                .call();
}
```

My intention here is clearly to update (locally) remote head and local head to the state that is on remote repository.

However, **only first ref in `setRefSpecs` gets updated**

My intention is clear here, update 2 references (remotes/origin/branchName, and heads/branchName) with one value (remotes/origin/branchName) with value.
 I have checked JGit code and I see that there is some sort of check that skips references based on source ref (that is why first argument is processed and second is not).

How to do it properly using `fetch` command? Do I really have to do `branchChreate` with `setForce(true)` to update the heads/branchName?

It would be convinient to have multiple destination `RefSpec`, but that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The `FetchCommand` will never change any of your local branches (like `refs/heads/foo`). It will only update remote tracking branches like `refs/remotes/origin/foo`).

The usual procedure is to fetch changes to a remote tracking branch and then merge or rebase or reset the local branch and the remote tracking branch.

If you would like to override local changes with whatever is fetched you should hard-reset your local branch to the remote tracking branch with the `ResetCommand`.

Assuming that `HEAD` points to `refs/heads/foo`, i.e. foo is checked out, you can use this code to reset the branch to its remote tacking branch:

```java
git.reset().setRef("refs/remotes/origin/foo").setMode(ResetType.HARD).call();
```

If the branch that should be reset isn't checked out, you can simply use `RefUpdate` like this:

```java
ObjectId remoteCommitId = repository.resolve("refs/remotes/origin/foo");
repository.updateRef("refs/heads/foo").setNewObjectId(remoteCommitId).forceUpdate();
```

Note, hoever, that in both cases you will lose all changes in the local branch.

Comment: *he FetchCommand will never change any of your local branches (like refs/heads/foo)* Unless i tested in badly, this is not true. I think I can update refs/heads with given code, but I guess i need to doublecheck that then. I will try `RefUpdate` as it does exaclty what I would like to do (as am working only on metadata, not checking out anything into wrokging directory)

Comment: I doubt that fetch touches anything in the refs/heads namespace and I'm curious to see the code that does so. But if so, wouldn't that solve our problem?

Comment: Yes it would, but then - as stated in question - if I pas multiple refspecs with the same source, only first one is getting processed. So using pure fetch with refspec I was able either to update remotes or heads, but not both. I am sure i saw the code that does that filtering somewhere.I will verify that once again.